# Do angels enter our houses during the time of the Maghrib prayer?

Tags: salat, islamic-basis, malaikah

I don't know if it's true but I've heard Muslims say that the time of the Maghrib prayer is a very blessed time and during this time, angels will enter your home and make dua for you.

Is this from any hadith?

Comment: What i know is not that, but from the hadith we should to protect our selfs in this time: See https://islamqa.info/en/127141

Comment: Asar time is very important, and there are a number of ahadees about it like this, are you sure you are asking about maghrib time not asar time? maybe you are translating sunset of something?

Answer (score 1):

The angels of succession and the angels who write down our deeds always stay with us. There are other types of angels who visit us at the dawn and the afternoon.

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger
>   of Allah (ﷺ) said, "There are angels who take turns in visiting you by
>   night and by day, and they all **assemble at the dawn (Fajr) and the
>   afternoon ('Asr) prayers.** Those who have spent the night with you,
>   ascend to the heaven and their Rubb, Who knows better about them,
>   asks: 'In what condition did you leave My slaves?' They reply: 'We
>   left them while they were performing Salat and we went to them while
>   they were performing Salat."'
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim, Sunnah.com reference   : Book 9, Hadith 60]

I have never come across any sahih hadiths that say anything about angels visiting us at the time of the Maghrib prayer. Perhaps you mixed up afternoon with Maghrib.